# Cuspform, elliptic curves and character sums

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I was trying to read through some note by Kowalski (see https://people.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/ik-ant-exp-sums.pdf). I was interested in trying to understand the following. The author states on page 313 that "One can also  think  this  way  about  the  real  character  sums  with  cubic  polynomials;  they are coefficients of a cusp form associated with an elliptic curve..." I assume that the author is referring to real-valued sums of the form $$\sum_{t\in (\mathbb{F}_q)^{\times}} \psi \big(f(t)\big),$$ where $\psi$ is an additive character on $\mathbb{F}_q$ (field with $q$ elements) and $f(t)\in \mathbb{F}_q[t]$ is a polynomial of degree 3.

First off, I'm sorry about the vague question. I really don't much about this subject, and I'm just curious. I would like if somebody gave a short (if possible) explanation how one can think of these sums as the coefficients of a cusp form. Or point me to a reference. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about character sums, but if $p$ is a prime, $\chi$ is the Legendre symbol modulo $p$ and $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$, then $a_p=-\sum_{x\in \mathbb F_p}\chi(f(x))$ is the $p$-th Fourier coefficient of the newform attached to the elliptic curve $y^2=f(x)$ by the modularity theorem. Thus the collection of all the $a_p$'s enjoy some particular property which comes from the fact that they are eigenvalues of a certain family of operators, named "Hecke operators".